# Unable to locate element in selenium Python in the iframe

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Below is my HTML code. I have tried by using xpath and still getting an exception of unable to locate element on a create account form. 
[image: HTML code]

Comment: You need to switch to the iframe first, then interact with the element. Please also post what have you tried, not only a picture.

Answer (score -1):

As the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()`.
- You can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#accountFrame[src='/account/frame/login/create']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Email'][data-test='create-account-email']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='accountFrame' and @src='/account/frame/login/create']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Email' and @data-test='create-account-email']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)
- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: thanks for the solution. It got fixed by switching the frames.

Comment: I cant see any tick mark in your comment therefore I have marked it as a useful comment.